# Error when I want to install eth-brownie with pipx

Tags: python, unicode, pipx, charmap

File "C:\Users\marqu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pipx\commands\install.py", line 60, in install
venv.install_package(
File "C:\Users\marqu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pipx\venv.py", line 238, in install_package
subprocess_post_check_handle_pip_error(pip_process)
File "C:\Users\marqu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pipx\util.py", line 349, in subprocess_post_check_handle_pip_error
print(completed_process.stderr, file=pip_error_fh, end="")
File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2502' in position 559: character maps to

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this first:
pip install cython

Followed by:
pip install eth-brownie